# firebug page elements (divs) path

Tags: wordpress, html, path

For example, I have a large wordpress site with a lot of plugins installed, I want to find the path of some divs to modify them. 
So, my questions is how can I find them easily, not to manually search on every folder of my wordpress site? 
Thanks!

Comment: How exactly can HTML elements/tags have paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go into Google Chrome and inspect an element, you'll see the full path in the bottom.

So for instance, your hosting here is

```
html body.question-page div.container div#content div#mainbar div#question.question table tbody tr td.postcell div div.post-text p
```